# How do I create a Quicktime reference MOV/clipping/instance using AVKit?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, quicktime, movie, mov

Using AVKit, how do I create an instance of a QT MOV, with user-defined in/out points?  Like the QTX Player's trim function, but instead of duplicating the data, save a file containing the reference data only.

QT7 used to create "movie clippings" like this, and could also save "reference only" movies that contained only the pointers to the specified segment of the original MOV.

Is this possible using AVKit?

If AVKit has no provision for this, could it be done by hacking a duplicate trimmed file, maybe by removing the video tracks, and converting it to a reference MOV?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That kind of thing cannot be done with a MOV file under iOS. The only kind of .mov supported is as a container for h.264 video data (it can also contain sound). But, there is no general purpose Quicktime functionality in iOS.